# Spark: Summary statistics

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark summary statistics as described at: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-statistics.html

According to Spark docs :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.{MultivariateStatisticalSummary, Statistics}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

val observations: RDD[Vector] = ... // an RDD of Vectors

// Compute column summary statistics.
val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary =     Statistics.colStats(observations)
```

I have a problem building `observations:RDD[Vector]` object. I try:

```
scala> val data:Array[Double] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
data: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

scala> val v = new DenseVector(data)
v: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]

scala> val observations = sc.parallelize(Array(v))
observations:   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector] =   ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:19

scala> val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(observations)
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
Note: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector <: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary =  Statistics.colStats(observations)
```

Questions:

1) How should I cast DenseVector to Vector?

2) In real program instead of array of doubles I have a to get statistics on a collection that I get from RDD using:

```
def countByKey(): Map[K, Long]
//Count the number of elements for each key, and return the result to the master as a Map.
```

So I have to do:

```
 myRdd.countByKey().values.map(_.toDouble)
```

Which does not make much sense because instead of working with RDDs I now have to work with regular Scala collections whiich at some time stop fitting into memory. All advantages of Spark distributed computations is lost.

How to solve this in scalable manner?

**Update**

In my case I have:

```
val cnts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = prodCntByCity.map(_._2) // get product counts only 
val doubleCnts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double] = cnts.map(_.toDouble)
```

How to convert `doubleCnts` into  `observations: RDD[Vector]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't need to cast, you just need to type:

```
val observations = sc.parallelize(Array(v: Vector))
```

2) Use `aggregateByKey` (map all the keys to to 1, and reduce by summing) rather than `countByKey`.

Comment: Thanks! Now another problem: how one can convert  `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]` to `RDD[Vector]` ?

Comment: First decide how you want to convert `Double` to `Vector`, then just `map` with that.

Comment: In my case I have just one column of double counts as RDD, that I need to get basic staistic on, such as mean, sd, quantiles... If I understand  this right to use MLib Statistics I need to build `val observations: RDD[Vector]`, for my case - a single Vector contained in RDD. So to achive this I need to convert `RDD[Double]` --> `DenseVector[Double] --> RDD[Vector]`. This conversion forces me to leave RDD space and go for in memmory `DenseVector[Double]` structure. Is it correct? If this is the case, again, all advantage of RDD is lost..

Comment: If your `RDD[Vector]` only contains a single `Vector` then of course there's no advantage to it being an `RDD`. `colStats` is intended to be used with an `RDD` of many small `Vector`s. If you just want the mean/variance etc. for a single data series you need to make an `RDD` of 1-element `Vector`s, not a 1-element `RDD` containing a big `Vector`.

Comment: Please see update of my question. It would be great if you could post a sample code to solve question in my update. Many thanks!

Comment: `val observations = doubleCnts.map{d => new DenseVector(d): Vector}`

Comment: Oh! I see now, every `double` becomes a  `vector` ! You right - does not make sense at all to use `colStats` for a single column! But what to use then to get statistics on a **very long** column that does not fit into memory?

Comment: `colStats` give you the average of first elements of vectors, the average of second elements of vectors and so on. If your vector was too long (implausibly so) you could just make two calls to `colStats`.

Answer (score 0):

DenseVector has a compressed function. so you can change the RDD[ DenseVector] to RDD[Vector] as :

```
    val st =observations.map(x=>x.compressed)
```